# Does adding a requirement to a question "deviates from the original intent of the post"?

Tags: discussion, edits, asking-questions

[A question has been edited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2878432/1446005) (not by the OP), and I would like a second opinion on the validity of such an edit.

Original question:

> How can I search for `foo`'s?

Edited into:

> How can I search for `foo`'s of type `bar`, where `bar` is a (variable) input parameter.

The edit essentially adds an extra requirement to the original question.

If such an edit popped into my review queue, I would immediately reject it with "clearly conflicts with author's intent. This edit deviates from the original intent of the post". However it comes from a user with edit privileges (>2k rep.).

Usually I would rollback the change. But the editor has put a large bounty on the new question, which makes me hesitant.

Pros:

- Quality edit, and the difference with the original question is clearly stated
- *Extension* on the original post, not exactly a *deviation*
- Has already attracted a decent-looking answer
- Has a large bounty pending

Cons:

- *Deviates* from the original post (yes, I am feeling schizophrenic right now)
- Feels a bit like thread hijacking
- Original question had an accepted answer

What do you recommend?

Comment: It looks like they completely hijacked the thread. I can't see why they didn't just make a new question.

Comment: I came so close to editing the title for this question, then realised my attempt at seasonal japes may not go down too well...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Whether an edit on a question "deviates from the original intention of the [question]" is answered by whether this edit will invalidate any existing (or potential) answers to the current question. Prior to the bounty set by the editor, there was one answer: the accepted answer. This answer could potentially be compromised by comments, downvotes and flags for not answering the bountied question, even though it did a fine job answering the original question (evidenced by acceptance by the original author of the question, no less). It may seem odd, but if you've seen the actions of less attentive reviewers, this becomes less surprising.

None of the pros you listed are pros, really. You never completely change an existing question, no matter how much better your new question is. Hijacking an existing question in order to immediately set a bounty for a *different* question is an abuse of the bounty feature as well. Some users have done this exact same thing as a result of being question-banned and faced severe consequences, and although this editor isn't question banned, it's likely they are trying to circumvent the bounty waiting period on new questions. Otherwise, there is no reason they couldn't just post it separately.

The point of allowing users to set bounties on other questions so that other users looking for solutions to the same problem can request answers, without having to duplicate the question. In this case, it's very clear that whatever the user replaced the original question with should have existed as a separate question.

If you notice that a user has placed a bounty on a question and changed it radically to suit their bounty, please flag it for moderator attention. We will remove the bounty and notify the editor (and anyone who has answered the bountied question).

Comment: I had flagged it for attention before you posted this answer. Glad to see I did the correct thing.

Comment: Thank you both, next time I won't hesitate.

Comment: I would just add one clarification, that adding a requirement to a question isn't *always* "deviating from the original intent" - that is, if the OP had made it clear that the requirement should always have been there (via commenting on the question or on answers, and answers not being accepted because they didn't fulfill his previously-unspecified requirements), then it would make complete sense to add it to the question if the OP didn't. I've seen that happen sadly too frequently. If the requirement *wasn't* ever requested by the OP, though, then yeah, totally invalid.

Comment: @neminem You could go a step further. Requirements the OP clarifies in the comments *should* be edited into the question. They are part of the question, and they should appear in it. A good way to ensure reviewers are aware the clarification came from the OP is to indicate it in the edit summary.

Comment: Agreed, @neminem.

Comment: I hope you annihilated the bounty with no refund for shenanigans like that.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Even if I wanted to I couldn't, sadly.

Comment: I feel like a refund *encourages* the misbehavior -- they got their attention, they got an answer (which you deleted because it was posted to the wrong question), they get their rep back, and no one else benefits (no rep to answerer, and no one else can use the answer except 10k users who stumble across it).  Pretty much the worst of all worlds.

Comment: This level of editing could have been a colleague. The OP never changed it or argued it either, despite being a regular SO user.

Comment: @TankorSmash: It's not OK to hijack someone else's post no matter who you are. The OP hasn't been around since September, so they wouldn't have been aware of the edit, let alone had a chance to dispute it. Still does not make it OK.

Comment: The only thing I disagree with in the post is `you never completely change a question that is not your own`.  **You should also never completely change your own question.**  You can clarify it and whatnot, but even if the original question was the asked by the guy who offered the bounty, that still would not be okay.

Comment: @Cody Piersall: Yeah, I didn't mean to imply it was OK to do the same to your own question. I was just focusing on the subject matter, which was editing other people's questions. I know some users get around their question bans by changing their own existing questions as well. I don't think anyone would disagree with you on that. I'll edit that portion in any case.

Comment: There is one rather unusual situation when it seems to be okay to completely change a question that is not your own: when the original question is horrible, the OP is non-responsive, and there is an excellent and highly upvoted answer.