# Edit Bounty Question to ask different question?

Tags: discussion

I have a open bounty for a question on StackOverFlow. I solved the question myself and since I can't give bounty to myself and none of the answers helped me. Is it rude/against rules to edit question to ask about about different problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your new question invalidates answers or comments, it is considered inappropriate. You are describing a chameleon question. You asked one question - and got two answers for that question - and then are completely changing the question so that those answers no longer make sense to the posted question.

My suggestion is to post your solution as an answer. It's true your bounty may not have paid off the way you planned, but by posting your answer you are providing future readers with a solution that worked. As a side effect, your answer may receive up votes that eventually offset the cost of the bounty. Another side effect is that you may receive an even better answer before the bounty expires.

One note about the active bounty: If you don't give the bounty to someone and one of the existing answers receives two up votes, half of the offered bounty will automatically be given to that user. If the answers truly don't work, consider down voting and posting a comment as to why it didn't work.

Comment: Yeah  I thought about those 2 answers. Guess I will do as you suggested. Wait for better answer, if not I'll post my answer. Thanks

Comment: Even if it doesn't invalidate any answers, editing the question to completely change what it's asking is still inappropriate.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281462/does-adding-a-requirement-to-a-question-deviates-from-the-original-intent-of-th/281463#281463