# Using a bounty to ask a different question

Tags: discussion, scope, bounty

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/206820/215552) has a bounty added by someone other than the OP which changes the scope of the question within the bounty text itself, without altering the original question.

I'm pretty sure this is discouraged, but can't seem to find a good Meta question about it. The problem, of course, is that the original answers are specific to the original question and the new question in the bounty is much broader. I don't want to down vote or flag the original question, as it seems to be a decent enough question.

Should I flag for moderator attention, or just let it go on its merry way?

---

This question is very similar to [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294862/215552) but differs as that question was about a horrible original question which needed to get closed anyway, and was answered as such.

It's also slightly similar to [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288546/215552), but that one is about editing the question to ask a different rather than using a bounty.

Comment: Also interesting here is that it was a *different* user that posted the bounty, not the OP.

Comment: I would look at it this way: Would answer to the question asked in the bounty _also_ answer the original question, without having to explicitly add a part for the original? If yes, leave it. If no, consider flagging for a mod.

Comment: @Kendra, I would answer that question "yes", with the caveat that the expanded question is, IMO, overly broad. So, certainly it would answer the original, but it could also be a book :).

Comment: The original Q was how to prevent/handle, the bounty blurb asks how to track and trace.  Similar - but definitely  different.  I kind of wonder why someone who puts up a 500rep bounty wouldnt compose their own question with all the particulars they need and want.

Comment: ...reading it again, I think they are more different than alike - they really only have the StackOverflowException in common.  The original is related to `XslCompiledTransform` whereas the bounty seems interested in a general approach.  I dont know that I would VTC though, because a solution might be interesting.

Comment: Yeah, I read the bounty text as "The original asked specifically about SOE on XslCompiledTransform, but I want to do something for all SOEs", which sounded difficult/impossible to answer, or at least better suited to some other site.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is not correct, he's asking an entirely different question.  You can certainly flag a moderator about that.  Do beware it isn't that likely he'll follow-up, they do give bounty sponsors a fair amount of latitude and it is rather a technical detail.  Use a custom flag and link to this meta Q+A.

On the other hand, it would be nice to get a better answer for the original question ;)

Comment: Your obviously right. That said, I had quite a bit of fun answering the bounty question and writing all the pieces of code to make it work. :-) And for me, it's all about the fun.