# What do you do when a question gets hijacked for a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

This question [Printing with sed or awk a line following a matching pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17908555/1745001) was asked 2 years ago by someone looking for a `sed` or `awk` answer. Several answers were given but none was selected as correct, the OP just disappeared. Since then the question has been viewed 27,000 times and one answer, mine, has gradually been accruing points.

A few days ago, a different user posted a bounty saying the question hasn't had enough attention but now insisting the answer must be using `sed` without the `-r` option.

When I asked the user why they did that instead of just posting a new question and referencing this one, the user said it was because they thought a new question would have gotten closed as a duplicate and they felt what they were doing was just fine because when the bounty ended, they would remove the new "`sed` without `-r`" requirement.

By that time, we'll be left with a question that has been chewed up and spit out with good answers having been downvoted, etc. and almost certainly with an answer selected that meets the "`sed` without `-r`" criteria but is FAR from the best answer to the original question, which is the only question that will still exist at that point. So people looking for an answer to that question in the future will find the question, see an answer selected and think that was the answer to the original question instead of the answer to the "`sed` without `-r`" bounty question.

What should/can we do when someone hijacks a question like that?

Comment: This seems like a bad thing for a bounty to do.  If it's acting like an edit that "conflicts with the author's intent" then that's a poor reason to post the bounty.  I'm not sure if you could explain everything in the space of a custom flag, so this meta question seems appropriate.

Comment: Hmmm... If they're trying to change a question through reputation/bounty manipulation, I would think that is grounds for a moderator flag for the bounty to be stopped and refunded. But I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: If only this question was on meta.SE so I could come back in 2 days and post a bounty asking for entirely unrelated information to be in an answer.  Missed opportunities...

Comment: I've recently had a similar problem. I was looking for an answer and came upon a post really close to what I was looking for, but not exactly. I figured I'd add a bounty instead of asking a new question that may have been a dup. I added in the description of my bounty specifically what I wanted. Some people saw it when they answered and some didn't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011538/how-to-send-a-variable-from-server-to-client-in-meteor , what I wanted was a bit different from the original question.

Comment: The bounty was removed by a moderator: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17908555/revisions

Comment: It was "without `-n`", wasn't it?

Comment: I don;t remember now. Doesn't matter either way though.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Yes, we'd treat it similarly to an edit in that regard (and so [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281462/does-adding-a-requirement-to-a-question-deviates-from-the-original-intent-of-th/281463#281463) becomes relevant).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If her question is different (such that the current question does not satisfy her requirements) she *needs to post a new question*.  One of the things we always tell people when disputing dupe closures is to explain why the dupe doesn't work.  If she can do that, her new question shouldn't get closed.

As it sits, she's used a bounty to make a temporary edit that changes the original question.  As an edit it would hopefully get rejected as conflicting with the author's intent.  So in my book this doesn't fly.

Flag it for mod attention and explain what's going on.  They should be able to remove the bounty and guide the user on what she should be doing.

Comment: Good idea thanks, I did that. Embarrassingly, I hadn't noticed the "flag" button under questions before!

Comment: Also EdMorton ironically if you'd done what I suggest above in a comment, ***ADDITIONALLY, YOU WOULD HAVE EASILY GOT THAT BOUNTY***. And indeed, that would have been well-desrved, everyone would want you to get that.  And, SM would (I'm guessing) have been very happy to see you have it.  And, the question would have been reverted back to "how it should be" so no worries there. And SM gets her answer. And your "go-to" answer of record would be even more go-to. (After all, good answers generally evolve with time, as technology changes.) Would have been win-win-win-win-win scenario!

Comment: @JoeBlow I couldn't care less about getting the bounty or any other SO points, but in any case my answer wouldn't have qualified for it as it isn't even using the tool required to satisfy the new requirement. How could the bounty poster possibly post a requirement to use "sed -r" (or -n, whatever it was) and then award the bounty to an answer that uses awk? In any case, I just wanted the posted answers to continue to match the original question and not to have a bunch of new answers to the new question cluttering things up, especially after the new requirement was removed.

Comment: @EdMorton you have such a high rep and been around so long and didn't notice the flag button, kinda nice really.. :)

Answer (score -21):

Exactly as SarahManning points out,

"everyone knows" that because of the occasional embarrassingly childish velocity close-voting on this site,

(just as she says, in the case of questions that are superficially "similar" to people who know nothing about the specific arcane field in question),

the only way to get a fast answer in these cases is using a "trick," such as the one at hand here.

Of course, the trick is not in line with behavior here, and will just be reversed.  (So, SarahManning, it's "their site" to do with as they like - you don't have any "rights"; if you try a whacky trick like that and it's reversed, such is life.)

{Indeed, SM, as many have mentioned on this page, the best solution I'd say is really just to post your new question, and, add many bold, large-typeface comments - use the simplest language possible - pointing out that the new question *is not* a dupe of the old question because of X Y Z.  (Limit yourself to words of one syllable in doing this.)}

But. It is **utterly ridiculous**, to not acknowledge, the extremely obvious situation that SManning describes.

Of course, "silly velocity close voting" is a social facet of this site; after all, nothing's perfect.

Comment: Wow, I guess nobody wants to hear about the childish velocity close voting.  Another reason close voting should be scaled to the size of the site (i.e., making it bigger than 5 on SO).  But no one will want to hear about that either.  After all, everything works so perfectly exactly as it is!  Except for when it doesn't, of course.

Comment: now that's sarcasm!  :)

Comment: @delicateLatticeworkFever: Maybe nobody wants to hear about "childish velocity close voting" because that's not a genuine problem. It's a problem *some people* have, but the majority of people have a different problem: bad questions being asked.

Comment: @delicateLatticeworkFever So you think system is broken and the solution for a fix is to break it some more??? And FYI, system works fine most of the time. There are occasional issues but that's why we have Meta.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I'm not equating imperfect with broken.  I'm expressing empathy with Joe Blow who was expressing empathy with "Sarah Manning".  The issue here does not really affect me personally.  If it is a purely binary issue for you then yes, of course the majority must always be respected or else we do not have a democracy (meaning we'd probably have something worse).  Not that SE is exactly democracy, but close enough, and there is no doubt in my mind where the majority opinion lies.  Put another way: You win, therefore you are right. :/

Comment: @delicateLatticeworkFever Maybe system is not perfect, actually nothing is, but I have zero empathy for people like Sarah Manning that only look at their own little interests and who cares about the rest. Want discuss the system, I am all ears. Want symphatize with people that don't care about others - couldn't be bothered.

Comment: @JoeBlow Agreed, democracy sucks. If rules don't fit...change the rules for benefit of all. Don't play the system for your own profit only.

Comment: I'm not condoning what Sarah did but I am empathizing, in the sense that I think it is *commonplace* for people who make prejudicial runs through the close queue to not bother with the reopen queue.  These people may also be acting out of their own particular interests without concern for the rest, and their abuse of the system inspires further abuse.  This implies some reflection upon the system may be a good thing.  I think that (reflection) should be an ongoing concern (versus a reactionary "Nothing is wrong, you just don't understand!") which is why I commented on the point.

Comment: @delicateLatticeworkFever There are 8K questions in close queue. While certainly exceptions can happen, I don't think that people are trigger happy with close voting. And IMO whether or not same people visit reopen queue does not matter. Number of questions in reopen queue is very small and improved questions do get reopened. If there is anything wrong with the system that is the fact we cannot close bad questions fast enough. Duplicates are another matter, though. But if question is not a duplicate, it should not be hard getting it reopened even if it does get mistakenly closed.

Comment: Ahh!  so that's why "dupe" close reason is used so indiscriminately.  Interesting!  (And, now I know that the way to get a crap question closed is mark it "dupe" - the other reasons won't happen. Good one.)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar The size of the close queue is no more evidence of the legitimacy of everything in it any more that the number of new questions is evidence for the legitimacy of all of them.   You are indicating problems with some percentage of people who ask questions; I agree, but I am further asserting those problems **do not end there** and also include people with close voting privileges, unfortunately.   Another solution may or may not be to scale that bar.  The more people with the privilege, the more work *they* may produce for other people reviewing their decisions.

Comment: @delicateLatticeworkFever agreed, there are problems with people asking questions, there are problems with people casting close votes, there are problems with _people_ in general because we don't all see the things the same way. But what I meant to say, is not that size of close queue is evidence of legitimacy, but that closing questions can be rather hard due to sheer number of questions there. Chances that people will successfully close question that didn't deserve closure are rather slim.

Comment: @delicateLatticeworkFever If and when close vote queue significantly drops down, then and only then we can potentially discuss trigger happy close voters that will close anything just because it is there and they didn't have worse questions to close down.

Comment: That's absurd.  That's like saying only when people stop asking so many questions can we potentially discuss bad questions.  Obviously this is not the case.  The fact that there are so many questions being asked does not mean it is impossible to point out a percentage of them, on a very regular basis, are bad questions.  Likewise people's use of other site features.

Comment: BTW, My whole initial point was that 5 votes is perhaps not enough on SO to ensure the mechanism is not being abused.  Or else the privilege bar is too low.  Whereas other places, these numbers -- which are exactly the same despite there being 1% the volume -- do not work for the opposite reason. They are not carefully decided upon values that maximize the efficacy of the system. They are simply arbitrary and historical. I would like to see a discussion of them, but this is frustrated by the same phenomenon that make Joe Blow's post here taboo -- the majority tend to see what they want to see.

Comment: "They are not carefully decided upon values that maximize the efficacy of the system. They are simply arbitrary and historical."  nicely put

Comment: @delicateLatticeworkFever You are off by mile in understanding what I am trying to say, not that this is your fault. I am not going into reasons why is close vote queue so large or whether or not will people stop asking bad questions. My whole point is that I don't see questions being closed willy-nilly as you and some others do. Bad close voting cases are rare exceptions and not the rule. This is where our opinions may differ. All your other points are valid but I cannot say that I fully agree or disagree with them at the moment. That is whole other discussion.

Comment: @JoeBlow If you look carefully, 5 is the only number that works. 3 is to low, and can possibly be abused, although when facing flood of bad questions many would probably be tempted to say 3 is right one. And 7 is just way to high when you take into account that need to close vote bad question fast outweighs need to prevent abuse. For later there is reopen queue, Meta and moderators. 5 provides proper balance.